# Virtual methods on a virtual base class

Tags: c++, methods, virtual, multiple-inheritance

Something that has been confusing me about virtual base class inheritance... Given the following classes:

```
class A
{
  virtual void foo() = 0;
}
class B : virtual A
{
  void foo() { /* do X */ }
}
class C : virtual A
{
  void foo() { /* do Y */ }
}
class D : B, C
{
}
```

Will this compile? If so, what would be the result of the following code:

```
D d;
A* a = &d;
a->foo();
```

Comment: I'm actually curious about the output of this as well...will B's foo be called, or will C's foo be called?

Comment: [Diamond Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem) and of course [the FAQ on the diamond](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.8).

Comment: Im guessing you'd get an error about an ambiguous function call.

Comment: Try it! You should get a compiler error because of the ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for the answers everybody; yes, I know I should have tried it myself, but that wasn't an immediate option, and I wanted an immediate answer ;) Thanks!

Comment: Other online C++ compilers than StackOverflow are available ;-) http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/, http://codepad.org/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should not compile, the function foo will be ambiguous. Since A::foo() is pure virtual function, the ambiguity has to be resolved.

Comment: Even if A::foo were not pure virtual, it would still be ambiguous and fail to compile

Comment: True. But the code has many other issues too. They are all privately inherited, foo() is a private function too.

Answer (score 4):

It won't compile for three reasons none of which has anything to do with virtual inheritance(well, maybe the last one).

1. You forgot the semicolons after class definitions
2. Your inheritance is private
3. `D::foo()` is ambiguous when not overriden explicitly

By the way, the definition of D itself is ill-formed, not just the fact that you try to use it. I mean if your `main()` function were empty, it still wouldn't compile.

And "Will this compile?" has the obvious answer "Why don't you try?"

Quote from the standard: 10.3.10

> The following example shows a function that does not have a unique
>   final overrider:

```
 struct A {
 virtual void f();
 };
 struct VB1 : virtual A { // note virtual derivation
 void f();
 };
 struct VB2 : virtual A {
 void f();
 };
 struct Error : VB1, VB2 { // ill-formed
 };
```

Comment: I realize I only wrote pseudo code, the point was that I don't have access to a compiler at the moment, and felt that most people could understand the code with some semicolons missing.

Answer (score 4):

It won't compile. GCC:

```
error: no unique final overrider for ‘virtual void A::foo()’ in ‘D’
```

You could have found that out yourself pretty fast.

Same with icc:

```
error #361: override of virtual function "A::foo" is ambiguous
```

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't:

```
diamond.cpp:24:7: error: request for member ‘foo’ is ambiguous
diamond.cpp:13:8: error: candidates are: virtual void C::foo()
diamond.cpp:8:8: error:                 virtual void B::foo()
```

This is called the *Diamond problem*, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem